# Localization of a static site

Tags: php, localization, web

I want to localize my website into several languages. After some deliberation it was decided to give a different version of the site files (php files with embedded translation) after a preliminary check for

```
$_SERVER ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]);
```

It is the right approach? If not, where you can read about the location of a competent, preferably about that which is localized to the example on facebook.com?

What to do with static sites? Where to check the browser language (given that the visitor can visit any page of the site and not just index.php)?
I'm not a programmer and I find it difficult to design these facilities so I do not have practice.
Sorry for so many questions :)

Comment: I always use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`on my sites and it works fine. But I never tried to find something on static websites.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Drupal? Drupal makes it very easy to manage & translate static pages, even for non-programmers. It automatically detects the best language and displays the correct translation. It also has the advantage that if you change the look of your site or if you add links to the menu, you don't need to change it on every single page. The PHP pages can easily be included as well, just activate PHP on the modules page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE but be prepared for errors. Have a clear and visible menu for your visitors that will allow them to switch languages.

There are also geolocation examples: determine where a user lives based on his ip address and serve the corresponding language. This is also, again, prone to error.